# How can I use Advanced Google Services within a Custom Google Sheet Function?

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-analytics-api, custom-function

I am trying to create a [custom Google Sheets function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) that pulls data from the [Analytics Reporting V4 API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4).  When I run this function from the App Scripts console, it successfully returns data.

When I run the function from within my spreadsheet, I get the following error:

> API call to analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet failed with error: Request is missing required
> authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication
> credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. (line 59).

Here is my function defined in the Apps Script Editor (again, this works fine when I press the run button from here):

[image: code editor screenshot]

And here is my error-producing spreadsheet implementation:

[image: formula edited in a cell screenshot]

[image: error screenshot]

Is there a way that I can make this work without having to use OAuth credentials?  From my understanding, the benefit of using Advanced Google Services is the ability to avoid this authentication flow, and I would like to take advantage of it.

Comment: Custom functions runs anonymously. So, you can't do that(at least not without weakening your Google account security)

Comment: What is the preferred way to handle this then?

Comment: You can substitute the custom function with any of the following: button, time-trigger, installed triggers  based on edit or on open.

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation:

`If your custom function throws the error message You do not have permission to call X service., the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function.
To use a service other than those listed above, create a custom menu that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps Script services.`

[Using Apps Script Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was searching for!